# Space travel & Dreaming in a short story

Tags: story-identification

I read a short story in a sci-fi anthology over ten years ago about (and here's where the details are fuzzy) space travel to a distant planet that required the passengers to sleep during the voyage.  After the trip, the protagonist wakes up and experiences life on the new planet only to find out later that it was a computer-generated simulation and that he was still asleep and dreaming on the ship.  Any ideas on the author or title?

Comment: The premise sounds sort of like [Old Twentieth](http://www.amazon.com/Old-Twentieth-Joe-Haldeman/dp/044101285X) although some of the extra details are dissimilar.

Comment: Arthur C. Clarke writes a lot about dreaming and space travel, especially in his short stories.

Answer (score 10):

It is undoubtedly ["Frozen Journey"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58195) by Philip K. Dick, also anthologized as "I Hope I Shall Arrive Soon".